UIButton/Configuration titleAlignment = .leading and imagePlacement = .trailing are not respected
        var configuration = UIButton.Configuration.bordered()
        configuration.image = ImageProvider.icon.history
        configuration.imagePlacement = .trailing
        historyButton.configuration = configuration
        configuration.titleAlignment = .leading
        historyButton.setTitle(String(localized: "History"), for: .normal)
        let image = ImageProvider.icon.history
        historyButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)


How could I get the title tethered to the leading edge of the button and image to the trailing edge? Thanks!
Changing alignment to leading moves both title and the image to the  leading edge.


The key is setting the button's .contentHorizontalAlignment to .fill...
var configuration = UIButton.Configuration.bordered()
configuration.image = UIImage(systemName: "gobackward.15")
configuration.title = "History"
configuration.imagePlacement = .trailing
let btn = UIButton(configuration: configuration)
    
btn.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
    
btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(btn)
let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
    btn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 60.0),
    btn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -60.0),
])

Result:

